# Struts button - How to prevent page refresh onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am using following code:

```
<s:submit type="input" value="clickme" onclick="func()"/>
```

and in `func()` I have an alert("hereee") but when I click it, it shows "hereee" in an alert window. But it also refreshes the page as well. How to prevent page refresh onclick event?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Eme Emertana: See my answer below with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return false` to prevent the page refresh.

```
<s:submit type="input" value="clickme" onclick="func(); return false;"/>
```

[**See Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/DtTxK/)

Comment: You may also `return false;` from the handler function.